# Prevent Config File From Publishing With Click-Once Deployment

Tags: c#, clickonce

I'm trying to use Click-Once publishing, trouble is, it's publishing also the Config file, which has the connection strings that I use on my development computer, not the correct ones I use in the production environment. How can I prevent the Config file from being published more than the first time? I tried in properties to not include it in the publishing list, but there is no option to do that.

Comment: I am not the author nor have any affiliation with the project, but there is a plugin for visual studio (free as in beer) that applies app.config transformations much like the built in web.config transformation engine works.  It's called SlowCheetah and it allows you to have different configuration settings based on your build profile.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WillBuikMSFT.SlowCheetah-XMLTransformsm  Meaning, you could publish a dummy config file when you do your Release deployment for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config files are part of Deployment since they store all the necessary settings which are used inside Addin.

If I understand the problem correctly then, you want to use some setting, say `HOSTURL=http://example.com` when Addin is in production environment and `HOSTURL=http://localhost` when you are developing the Addin and you are expecting all this to automatically without human involvement.

Then, you may try one of these:

[1] Try find the `ClickOnceLocation` and use settings depending upon value the `ClickOnceLocation`. 
Assuming `ClickOnceLocation` contains `"Debug"` while you are developing/debugging the Addin.

```
//CodeBase is the location of the ClickOnce deployment files
Uri uriCodeBase = new Uri(assemblyInfo.CodeBase);
string ClickOnceLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(uriCodeBase.LocalPath.ToString());
if(ClickOnceLocation.Contains("Debug"))
{
    URL = "http://localhost";    
}
else
{
    URL = //from app.config
}
```

[2] [Updating the app.config by using build configurations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2010/03/09/tricks-with-app-config-and-clickonce-deployment-saurabh-bhatia/)

There are some tricks you could use so that a different file with the values to the production server get picked up during publish.

You can have two separate config files one for local deployment/debugging and one for a real published or production version of the application. The debugging config file could point to the localhost server whereas the real published config file could point to the real server. You can then configure the build configurations such that the appropriate config file is picked up depending on the Active build configuration.

To add two different app.config files to the project, you can update the reference to app.config in your project file. The app.config is defined in the project file (vbproj or csproj) with the following xml:

```
<ItemGroup>

…

<None Include=”app.config” />

</ItemGroup>
```

There may be other nodes in the ItemGroup along with the app.config node. Delete the just app.config from this ItemGroup node and create a new ItemGroup under the  node with the following xml:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=” ‘$(Configuration)|$(Platform)’ == ‘Debug|AnyCPU’ “>
<None Include=”app.config” />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=” ‘$(Configuration)|$(Platform)’ == ‘Release|AnyCPU’ “>
<None Include=”publishedapp.config” />
</ItemGroup>
```

This basically means that the regular app.config file will be used when the Active configuration is set to Debug and the modified app.config with the real production variables stored in the “published” subfolder of the project is used when the active configuration is set to “Release”.

You can change the ItemGroup conditions to match other build configurations that you may have defined. One possibility is to have a separate “Publish” configuration defined based on the “Release” configuration but only used when you are actually going to publish an application.

An additional disclaimer with this process is that the VS project system itself and the designers are not aware of the additional app.config file; Visual Studio is only aware of the original file. The modified app.config with values for a production environment is only used by the msbuild process. So if you update the main app.config through the Settings Designer, the modified app.config will not be updated and you have to manually update the file.

Once you have configured your project appropriately you can simply switch between the different build configurations to change the config file and publish the application from Visual Studio without having to go through the update and re-sign process.

Comment: Big Thanks To All Answerers, i will study the stuff and mark them acordingly